# Implement GenericAlias in a user-defined class (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, type-hinting

From PEP 585, you can specify, for example, the type of the elements in a list:

```
arr: list[int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

`list[int]` is of type `GenericAlias`, and is equivalent to `GenericAlias(list, int)`.
I would like to implement this functionality in a custom class. For example:

```
>>> MyClass[int]
MyClass[int]
>>> x: MyClass[int] = MyClass(42)
```

If I create a class that inherits from list, it works, so I guess it's due to an attribute.

I already tried class methods or static methods:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, Class: type):
        return GenericAlias(cls, Class)
```

But it didn't work. I get the error `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Implementing any methods yourself is the wrong way to go. Use a type variable and [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) instead. (There's gotta be a dupe target for this somewhere.)

Comment: I found `__class_getitem__`, that works. Could you explain better this other way?

Comment: If you implement `__class_getitem__`, you will successfully create a `GenericAlias` instance at runtime, but static type checkers will not understand your annotations, and you won't be able to annotate things like "`MyClass[T].whatever()` returns a `T`".

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to implement this functionality in a custom class.

You did not explain what exactly you mean by *"this functionality"*. I assume what you *actually* want to do is define your own generic class, which is to say a class that is generic in terms of at least one specific type.

This has been covered in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) already and discussed multiple times in various configurations on this site. I suggest you read through the PEP section.

I would discourage you from relying on `__class_getitem__` for your type annotation purposes as I doubt it will be properly supported by static type checkers any time soon. (see [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11501) for example). Besides, there is just no need for it, if you can simply subclass [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic).

If you want to do *other* things inside `__class_getitem__`, you are of course free to do so, but don't expect static type checkers to even consider your implementation.

In short:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class MyClass(Generic[T, U]):
    pass


Cls = MyClass[int, str]
print(Cls)  # MyClass[int, str]
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Use `__class_getitem__` instead of `__getitem__`:

```
from types import GenericAlias

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def __class_getitem__(cls, klass: type):
        return GenericAlias(cls, klass)
```

`@classmethod` is not need if `__class_getitem__` is defined on a class: this is the default.

See also [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types). But take note of the following two paragraphs:

> To implement custom generic classes that can be parameterized at runtime and understood by static type-checkers, users should either inherit from a standard library class that already implements `__class_getitem__()`, or inherit from `typing.Generic`, which has its own implementation of `__class_getitem__()`.

> Custom implementations of `__class_getitem__()` on classes defined outside of the standard library may not be understood by third-party type-checkers such as mypy. Using `__class_getitem__()` on any class for purposes other than type hinting is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking for a solution for hours...